# SQLite database as set

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I need to remember some single values in my android project. But all examples I saw was about storing data of the same type. What is the best way to use SQLite database here?

Comment: Do you need a database, or might SharedPreferences be enough?

Comment: Clear your requirement please, so we can help you better .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at SharedPreferences here's example:

```
SharedPreferences mShared = getSharedPreferences("your package name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor mSharedEdit = mShared.edit();
//Saving String
mSharedEdit.putString("key", "value").commit();
//Getting it back
mShared.getString("key","value if not exists");
```

More here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html